# Derivative of vector-valued function divided by norm

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, derivatives, jacobian, hessian-matrix

Let $g:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ be some gradient function. I would like to compute the Jacobian of $g$ (i.e. Hessian) divided by its norm. I know
$$
\nabla_x g(x) = H(x)
$$
What is
$$
\nabla_x \frac{g(x)}{||g(x)||} = ?
$$

Comment: This is what I get
$$
\nabla_x g(x)\left(g(x)^\top g(x)\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}} = \frac{H(x)}{||g(x)||} - \frac{1}{2} g(x)^\top\left[g(x)^\top g(x)\right]^{-\frac{3}{2}} 2 g(x) H(x) = \frac{H(x)}{||g(x)||} - \frac{H(x)}{||g(x)||} = 0
$$
which surely is wrong?

Comment: Somehow I believe the true answer should be $\frac{H(x)}{||g(x)||}$

Comment: I have a feeling I am messing up the chain rule